# Which methods must I override to enable drag&drop in Squeak?

Tags: drag-and-drop, smalltalk, squeak, morphic

I have a big morph with dozens of submorphs. The submorphs are of two kinds: pieces and squares.

I have googled a lot and read quite a bit of Morphic documentation, but somehow I can’t get it to work. I have not yet found a document that clearly explains what to do.

Currently, the pieces won’t be dragged (except when I Alt-click on them). The squares have implemented the mouseEnterDragging and mouseLeaveDragging methods and they are being called (they change the color of the squares, so it’s easy to spot). But it’s like something invisible is being dragged.

What I want: the pieces should be draggable, just by holding down the left mouse button and moving the mouse, not by using Alt-click to bring up the halo. The squares should not be draggable. The pieces should be droppable on squares, but not on pieces.

Which methods should I implement/override?

Comment: Have you tried sending `enableDrag: true` to the pieces?

Comment: Yes I have. The behavior is that when I try to drag one piece, everything is dragged, the base morph, so to speak, which is the owner of all other morphs, and everything with it.

Comment: I would try this: when your piece receives `startDrag:` send `grabMorph:`. Depending on the result, you may need to do more. Not sure if you also need to `removeMorph:` the piece from its owner.

Comment: I have overridden both handleMouseDown: and startDrag: Both methods are not called. I have disabled drag for all morphs, except the piece morphs, yet when I try to drag a piece, the complete board, with everything on it, is dragged. If I look at “documentation”, all I read is that I should override certain methods. But it doesn’t say what the methods should contain. What I am looking for are precise instructions on what methods to override with what content. Surely I don’t have to program dragging by myself? I should be able to use standard behavior?

Comment: I'm not a Squeak user so I can't tell. Post the question to the [Squeak-dev list](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/squeak-dev). If you don't get an answer, come back to me. I'll find the right person to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with a `mouseDown:` event, the hand can then observe the following `mouseMove:` or `mouseUp:` events to give the interested morph a callback about click, double-click, or start-drag.

So, your to-be-dragged morph should implement `handlesMouseDown:` and `mouseDown:` and in the latter send `waitForClicksOrDrag:event:` to the hand, which is in the `event` you get as argument in `mouseDown:`.

You may refine the callback via `waitForClicksOrDrag:event:selectors:threshold:` but the default callbacks are `click:`, `doubleClick:`, `doubleClickTimeout:`, and `startDrag:`.

A simple way to implement a `startDrag:` (or similar) is `event hand grabMorph: self`.

Then, for the dropping, there is a simple handshake via `wantsDroppedMorph:event:` and `wantsToBeDroppedInto:` and finally `acceptDroppingMorph:event:`. Those are simply configured via `dropEnabled`. You can but you don't have to use (i.e., drag-and-drop) the surrogate `TransferMorph`.

You can read more about the mechanism by reading the following source code (and other senders/implementors) in the image:

- `HandMorph >> #waitForClicksOrDrag:event:`
- `Morph >> #startDrag:`
- `Morph >> #handleDropMorph:`

Besides implementing stuff in a subclass of `Morph`, you can also script it from the outside via `eventHandler`:

```
m := Morph new.
m eventHandler: EventHandler new.
m eventHandler handlesClickOrDrag: true.
m on: #startDrag send: #value:value: to: [:event :source |
    Transcript showln: 'drag start'.
    event hand grabMorph: source].
m openInHand.
```

This will free you from having to bother with `waitForClicksOrDrag:event:`.

Hope this helps! Happy Squeaking. :-)